# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'XYZ' available as reques t attribute

Tags: spring-mvc

**class META_INF**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "META_INF")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class META_INF {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean locked;

    @ManyToOne
    private USER lockedBy;

    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    private USER createBy;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean active = true;

    private String version;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean log;

    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "CONTEXTE")
    @ManyToOne
    private PRM_CONTEXTE CONTEXTE;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "INSIDE_CREATION_TS")
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
    private LocalDate INSIDE_CREATION_TS;
}
```

**class PIL_P_APPLCTN**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PIL_P_APPLCTN")
public class PIL_P_APPLCTN extends META_INF {

    @NotBlank
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, name = "APPLCTN_CD")
    private String APPLCTN_CD;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "APPLCTN_ID")
    private String APPLCTN_ID;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "APPLCTN_DS")
    private String APPLCTN_DS;

    @NotNull
    @Digits(integer = 20, fraction = 0)
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "DECLG_IDNTFNT_NU")
    private BigDecimal DECLG_IDNTFNT_NU;
}
```

**Controller AppController**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@SessionAttributes("roles")
public class AppController {

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppController.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("pIL_P_APPLCTN_SERVICE")
    IService<PIL_P_APPLCTN> appService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("pRM_CONTEXTE_SERVICE")
    IService<PRM_CONTEXTE> cntxtService;

    @Autowired
    MessageSource messageSource;
@RequestMapping(value = { "/addApp" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newApp(ModelMap model) {
        PIL_P_APPLCTN application = new PIL_P_APPLCTN();
        List<PRM_CONTEXTE> cntxt = cntxtService.findAllOBJECTS();
        model.addAttribute("cntxt", cntxt);
        model.addAttribute("application", application);
        model.addAttribute("edit", false);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getFullName());
        return "formApp";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/addApp" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveApp(@Valid PIL_P_APPLCTN application, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "formApp";
        }

        if (!appService.isObjectFieldUnique(application.getId(), application.getAPPLCTN_CD())) {
            FieldError app_cdError = new FieldError("application", "APPLCTN_CD", messageSource.getMessage("non.unique.APPLCTN_CD",
                    new String[] { application.getAPPLCTN_CD() }, Locale.getDefault()));
            result.addError(app_cdError);
            return "formApp";
        }

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        Date dt1 = new Date();
        String dt2 = formatter.format(dt1);
        Date date = null;
        LocalDate dateF = null;
        try {
            date = formatter.parse(dt2);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dateF = new LocalDate(date);

        application.setCreateBy(userService.findBySSO(getPrincipal()));
        application.setINSIDE_CREATION_TS(dateF);
        application.setLocked(false);
        application.setLockedBy(null);
        application.setVersion("INITIAL");
        application.setLog(false);
        //application.setCONTEXTE(cntxtService.findById(application.getCONTEXTE().getId()));

        appService.saveOBJECT(application);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getFullName());
        // return "success";
        return "redirect:/appli";
    }
}
```

**formApp.jsp**

```
 <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="application" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" >
                    <form:input type="hidden" path="id" id="id"/>


                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="active">ACTIVE</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="">                            
                              <form:checkbox id="active" path="active" name="active" class="js-switch"  />

                                <form:errors path="active"/>

                          </div>

                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="item form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="APPLCTN_CD">APPLCTN CD </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <form:input type="text" path="APPLCTN_CD" id="APPLCTN_CD" name="APPLCTN_CD" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"/>

                                <form:errors path="APPLCTN_CD"/>

                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="item form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="APPLCTN_ID">APPLCTN ID 
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <form:input type="text" path="APPLCTN_ID" id="APPLCTN_ID" name="APPLCTN_ID"   class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"/>

                                <form:errors path="APPLCTN_ID"/>

                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="item form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="APPLCTN_DS">APPLCTN DS 
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <form:input type="text" path="APPLCTN_DS" id="APPLCTN_DS" name="APPLCTN_DS"   class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"/>

                                <form:errors path="APPLCTN_DS"/>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="item form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="DECLG_IDNTFNT_NU">DECLG IDNTFNT NU
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <form:input type="text" path="DECLG_IDNTFNT_NU" id="DECLG_IDNTFNT_NU" name="DECLG_IDNTFNT_NU"  class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"/>

                                <form:errors path="DECLG_IDNTFNT_NU"/>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="item form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="CONTEXT">CONTEXT</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <form:select itemValue="id" path="CONTEXTE" itemLabel="CONTEXTE_CD" items="${cntxt}" class="select2_single form-control" tabindex="-1" />

                                <form:errors path="CONTEXTE"/>


                        </div>
                      </div>



                      <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                            <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${edit}">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="location.href='<c:url value='/appli' />'">Annuler</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onClick="location.href='<c:url value='/edtApp' />'">Modifier</button>
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="location.href='<c:url value='/appli' />'">Annuler</button>
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Ajouter"/>
                                </c:otherwise>
                            </c:choose>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form:form>
```

**messages.properties**

```
NotBlank.pil_p_applctn.APPLCTN_CD=Champ obligatoire !
NotBlank.pil_p_applctn.APPLCTN_ID=Champ obligatoire !
NotNull.pil_p_applctn.APPLCTN_DS=Champ obligatoire !
NotBlank.pil_p_applctn.DECLG_IDNTFNT_NU=Champ obligatoire !
Digits.pil_p_applctn.DECLG_IDNTFNT_NU=Seules les données numériques sont acceptées avec max 20 chiffres !
non.unique.APPLCTN_CD={0} existe déjà !
```

When i'm insering valid data in the form, the object is persisted in DB, but when i'm trying to insert wrong data the error messages in **messages.properties** are not shown.. and got this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'application' available as reques
t attribute
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:217)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1243)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'application' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.formApp_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(formApp_jsp.java:2155)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.formApp_jsp._jspService(formApp_jsp.java:554)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:402)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:346)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.jsp.JspFileHandler.handleRequest(JspFileHandler.java:32)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:265)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:200)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:193)
    ... 78 more
```

Thanks for any advices ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here is the error comming...

```
 @RequestMapping(value = { "/addApp" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String saveApp(@Valid PIL_P_APPLCTN application, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return "formApp";
            }

            if (!appService.isObjectFieldUnique(application.getId(), application.getAPPLCTN_CD())) {
                FieldError app_cdError = new FieldError("application", "APPLCTN_CD", messageSource.getMessage("non.unique.APPLCTN_CD",
                        new String[] { application.getAPPLCTN_CD() }, Locale.getDefault()));
                result.addError(app_cdError);
                return "formApp";
            }
```

Thus your code shuold be:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/addApp" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String saveApp(@Valid @ModelAttribute("application") PIL_P_APPLCTN application, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
            model.addAttribute("application", application);

            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return "formApp";
            }

            if (!appService.isObjectFieldUnique(application.getId(), application.getAPPLCTN_CD())) {
                FieldError app_cdError = new FieldError("application", "APPLCTN_CD", messageSource.getMessage("non.unique.APPLCTN_CD",
                        new String[] { application.getAPPLCTN_CD() }, Locale.getDefault()));
                result.addError(app_cdError);
                return "formApp";
            }
```

**formApp.jsp**

```
<form:form method="POST" commandeName="application" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" >
                    //....
 </form:form>
```

Comment: hi
when i add the attribute in model.. the error is not shown **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'application' available as request attribute**, but also the custom message errors are not shown ..

Comment: If you mean for obligatory field errors than 1-make sure not to pass a `new PIL_P_APPLCTN () `object because that would override the object containing the errors and 2- remove  `model.addAttribute("application", application); ` from where I have placed to before the `return "formApp"; `

Comment: stiil cant display custom messages :/

Comment: If your code is the same as the one here than it's normal, you haven't set error messages in your entity `@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter something.")` see: [


 
Free Java 
Tutorial Videos
Name:

Email:

Send Me
We respect your privacy

Spring MVC Form Validation Example](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-form-validation-example-with-bean-validation-api)

Comment: Yes you are right, but the command is missing in the form declaration
`ConstraintName.CommandName.propertyName=validation error message` or  try using the modelAttribute name as your CommandName

Comment: lool i managed to display the default messages but not mine :D